# how do I merge the values of the child components of angular2 into reactive form object?

Tags: angular

I 'am using reactive form of angular2.  In between the the form fields,  I have so many components.  I want to know how do I merge the values of these components into my form object?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do you have some sample code of what you mean?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am unable to post my code from mobile.  I have a child component that is a date component.